# Entity Framework Core wrong format date in database but read correct

Tags: asp.net-core, datetime, entity-framework-core

I'm working on my project with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and Entity Framework Core. I have a table with a column of `Date` datatype:

```
[Column(TypeName = "Date")]
[Required]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Recently when I insert data in this table, date is inserted like below:

[image]

It is marvelous that when I read data from this table to show in calendar plugin, date is correct format:

[image]

This is my code for save data in database:

```
var dtDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
_db.ImPossibleReserveDates.Add(new ImPossibleReserveDate
{
    Date = dtDate.Date,
    InsertTime = DateTime.Now,
    IsRemoved = false
});
```

And this code for read data:

```
var list = _db.ImPossibleReserveDates.Where(x => !x.IsRemoved).Select(x => new
{
    date = x.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    TITLE = "تعطیل"
});
```

No matter in server or local!

Why did this happen?

Comment: Did you insert the time data for the 2643 part manually or did you insert it through code?

Comment: @Chaodeng, I inserted date field through code.

Answer (score 0):

check your converted date in server before save it
its seem two convert in your date

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You must enter the date in solar form (11-17-1400) then it will be automatically stored in the database based on Gregorian calendar.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).